# Instagram API bad request : Please supply a valid action from the following: follow, unfollow, approve, ignore, block, unblock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, request, instagram, instagram-api

I can't manage to send the action "follow" as postdata when I'm doing a POST request to the Instagram API. I'm trying to make a button_to in my rails app.

Here is the erb code :

```
<%= button_to "Follow", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/*[user_id]*/relationship?access_token=*[token]*", data: {action: "follow"} %>
```

The by default method for *Button_to* is POST so I don't need to specify that. And I have to send the "follow" action in the request body, but I don't see how.

Any help ?

Comment: you can use action as query parameter in your url like this: /v1/users/{user_id}/relationship?access_token=*[token]*&action=follow

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the Params to the url, like so:

```
?access_token=*[token]*&action=follow
```